# Crontab can't reach several Macs?

Tags: osx, cron, macintosh, ping

I made a script where the first step is to check if a Mac is even online (otherwise it would be unnecessary to even start the script). In the terminal it works perfectly fine: everything runs as it is supposed to.

I want to run it via a cron job at 23:30 at night, so I created a cron job and logged the whole thing.  The log however says that the Ping failed for the Macs, but they are definitely online.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Here is the script itself:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#Array of Mac hostnames separated by spaces
my_macs=( Mac111 Mac121 Mac122 Mac123 Mac124 Mac126 Mac127 Mac128 Mac129 )

# Number of days the remote Mac is allowed to be up
MAX_UPDAYS=1

CURR_TIME=$(date +%s)
MAX_UPTIME=$(( MAX_UPDAYS * 86400 ))
ADMINUSER="pcpatch"

#Steps through each hostname and issues SSH command to that host
#Loops through the elements of the Array

echo "Remote Shutdown Check vom $(date)" >> /Users/pcpatch/desktop/shutdown/Log/remoteshutdown.log
for MAC in "${my_macs[@]}"
do
    echo -n "Überprüfe ${MAC}... " >> /Users/pcpatch/desktop/shutdown/Log/remoteshutdown.log
    # -q quiet
    # -c nb of pings to perform

    if ping -q -c3 "${MAC}" >/dev/null; then
        echo "${MAC} ist angeschaltet. Laufzeit wird ermittelt... " >> /Users/pcpatch/desktop/shutdown/Log/remoteshutdown.log

        BOOT_TIME=0
        # Get time of boot from remote Mac
        BOOT_TIME=$(ssh "${ADMINUSER}@${MAC}" sysctl -n kern.boottime | sed -e 's/.* sec = \([0-9]*\).*/\1/')

        if [ "$BOOT_TIME" -gt 0 ] && [ $(( CURR_TIME - BOOT_TIME )) -ge $MAX_UPTIME ]; then
            echo "${MAC} ist über 24 Stunden online. Shutdown wird ausgeführt!" >> /Users/pcpatch/desktop/shutdown/Log/remoteshutdown.log
            ssh "${ADMINUSER}@${MAC}" 'sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now'
        else
            echo "${MAC} ist noch keine 24 Stunden online. Shutdown wird abgebrochen!" >> /Users/pcpatch/desktop/shutdown/Log/remoteshutdown.log
        fi

    else
        echo "${MAC} ist nicht erreicbar Ping (Ping fehlgeschlagen)" >> /Users/pcpatch/desktop/shutdown/Log/remoteshutdown.log
    fi
done
```

In the cron job I wrote:

```
30 23 * * * /User/myuser/Shutdown/Shutdown.sh
```

Comment: Are ICMP packets allowed on the Macs?

Comment: What error message from the `ping`s themselves? Does the script run directly (ie not from `cron`). Does the test-if-online part work from `cron` during the day when you can personally verify the remote devices are switched on?

Comment: @roaima the pings don't leave an error message, only my own message that the ping can't connect. 

The script (and the pings) work fine when I start the script through the terminal instead of a cron. 


Yes, I tested it earlier if the Macs were online, but the ping still says that there is no connection. This only happens during the cronjob

Comment: Without knowing the contents of your script it is not easy to answer. You should keep in mind that you have to give the full path to all commands/executables/scripts in your script, as `cron` by default only features a very limited `PATH` variable (usually only `/bin:/usr/bin`, see `man 5 crontab`)

Comment: @ridgy I now edited my post so the complete script is there and that the line from crontab is also there

Comment: I can't see any problem - but depending on your OS (you did not tell about) maybe you'ld have to use full paths to ping, ssh, date etc. And just for testing replace your ping with `ping -c3 "${MAC}" >> /Users/pcpatch/desktop/shutdown/Log/remoteshutdown.log 2>&1`.

Comment: My OS is El Capitan (OSX 10.11

Comment: @ridgy The logging of the ping doesn't change anything and just says that it is not reachable

Comment: Is that "_logging of the ping_" the actual output of the `ping` command, or just your interpretation of the command exit status?

Comment: If you remove the `-q` flag and the redirect of ping's output, do you see anything more useful?  It's likely that ping isn't in your crontab `$PATH`.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to simplify the script as much as possible when fault-finding: make it simply ping a single host and report the exit status.  When you have the simple case working, then extend it to loop over the host list and do the rest of the actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an explicit `PATH` for a script to be run under `cron`. The default is `PATH=/usr/bin:bin` and you need (at least) `/sbin` there.

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
...
```

You could also consider tweaking the options on the `ping` test slightly. The `-o` allows `ping` to exit as soon as it receives one response (i.e. the host is awake). The `-W1000` forces an upper bound on the time it will wait for a rely. In my tests this caused `ping` to wait for a maximum of four seconds; without it I had to wait 14 seconds for a failure response:

```
ping -q -c3 -o -W1000 "${MAC}"
```